# Troubleshooting a method

Tags: java, methods

Im wondering if anyone of you could take a look at my method code and help me figure out what makes it faulty? It`s a simple task about determing wheter or not two rectangles overlap/intercept/touch eachother. I searched around on the forum and studied the separating axis test/theorem. It works. partly. But the problem occur when i have two rectangles that dont have the same dimensions.
Heres the code:

```
    public boolean contains(MyRectangle2D x, MyRectangle2D y){

    if(Math.abs(xAxisDistance(x, y)) - Math.abs(centerToPerimeterXDistance(x)) - Math.abs(centerToPerimeterYDistance(y)) > 0)
        return false;
    if(Math.abs(yAxisDistance(x, y)) - Math.abs(centerToPerimeterXDistance(x)) - Math.abs(centerToPerimeterYDistance(y)) > 0)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}

public double xAxisDistance(MyRectangle2D x, MyRectangle2D y){
    return x.getXCenter() - y.getXCenter();
}
public double yAxisDistance(MyRectangle2D x, MyRectangle2D y){
    return x.getYCenter() - y.getYCenter();
}
public double centerToPerimeterXDistance(MyRectangle2D x){
    return x.getWidth()/2;

}

public double centerToPerimeterYDistance(MyRectangle2D x){
    return x.getHeight()/2;
}
```

In short: I have two if-sentences. one check the x-axis, and the other one checks the y-axis. And if the distances between the circles is less than 0. they overlap. It works fine when the circles have the same dimensions, but if one circle have a larger Height for eksample. it "overlaps" when its far away.

Any input that can push me in the right direction to solve this is appretiated!

[image: Heres what the program looks like]

Comment: I could not reproduce your problem. Probably your mistake is in another part of the code. (Maybe a wrong getter or setter in `MyRectangle2D`?)

Comment: Yeah, that might well be it. ill look into it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was in my contains-method.

i was supposed to substract the `centerToPerimeterXDistance`of both the rectangles. 
But instead i had `centerToPerimeter_Y_Distance` mixed in. Just changed it to X. and it worked like a charm :D

Answer (score 0):

I wonder whether you are talking about "circles" in the second paragraph. And admittedly, I did not entirely understand what you are actually computing there at the moment.

However, a suggestsion: For the intersection tests, some small helper methods may be ... helpful:

```
private static float getMinX(MyRectangle2D r)
{
    return r.getXCenter() - r.getWidth() / 2;
}
private static float getMinY(MyRectangle2D r)
{
    return r.getYCenter() - r.getHeight() / 2;
}
private static float getMaxX(MyRectangle2D r) 
{ 
    return r.getXCenter() + r.getWidth() / 2; 
}
private static float getMaxY(MyRectangle2D r) 
{ 
    return r.getYCenter() + r.getHeight() / 2; 
}
```

With these, the intersection tests become quite simple:

```
private static boolean intersect(MyRectangle r0, MyRectangle r1)
{
    if (getMaxX(r0) < getMinX(r1)) return false; 
    if (getMaxY(r0) < getMinY(r1)) return false; 
    if (getMinX(r0) > getMaxX(r1)) return false; 
    if (getMinX(r0) > getMaxY(r1)) return false; 
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Its supposed to be rectangles in the second paragraph, sorry :P